# Patrol Read Aborted on PD

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, raid, megaraid

Getting “Patrol Read Aborted on PD" warning message on MegaRAID Storage Manager. After research I found that Patrol Read and Consistency Check (CC) was scheduled by controller to run at the same time (which not supposed to happen) on IBM web site if CC and RP are running at the same time I should get " ServeRAID Event Log Message: "Patrol Read can't be started" message. I'm trying to figure out if this error occurs for the same reason or it's related to something else.

Comment: The CC likely just preempted the PR. Are there any error messages?

Comment: this are warinning messages

Comment: I think you can safely ignore the messages, configure either CC or PR, and move along... but I'm sure someone with some better expertise will chime in afterwhile.